# Generation of child lists from a mother list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of N objects in input and I would like to group in daughter lists the objects of the same family. Objects in the same family share the attribute "File_identifier". Finally I would like to access these daughter lists via a key being an attribute of one of the objects of the daughter list.

SentinelReportModels is the parent list

```
HashMap<String, List<SentinelReportModel>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<SentinelReportModel>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentinelReportModels.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < sentinelReportModels.size(); k++) {
            if (sentinelReportModels.get(i).getIdentifiantfichier()
                    .equals(sentinelReportModels.get(k).getIdentifiantfichier()) ) {
                ArrayList<SentinelReportModel> listeTemp = new ArrayList<>();
                listeTemp.add(sentinelReportModels.get(i));
                listeTemp.add(sentinelReportModels.get(k));

                hashmap.put(sentinelReportModels.get(i).getTypeflux(),listeTemp);
            }
        }

    }
```

However it does not work, I get X lists with duplicates.

Comment: Please give definition of `SentinelReportModel` class, what you post if not enough, collect if same `idFichier` but key is `typeFlux` ?

Comment: You create a new arraylist everytime there's a match

Comment: Please when you ask question, stay around for the next minute, or wait to ask, they are the crucialest minutes, we won't stay hours for your answer to our comment (and you went to edit your post by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the below code should do the trick. It is basically, putting all the setinels with same Flux in a list. If flux id is different a new list is added to the map.

```
HashMap<String, List<SentinelReportModel>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<SentinelReportModel>>();


hashmap.put(,listeTemp);

for (int i = 0; i < sentinelReportModels.size(); i++) {
    if (hashMap.get(sentinelReportModels.get(i).getTypeflux())==null) {


ArrayList<SentinelReportModel> list = new ArrayList<SentinelReportModel>();
  list.add(sentinelReportModels.get(i));
hashMap.put(sentinelReportModels.get(i).getTypeflux(),list);
        }else {             hashMap.get(sentinelReportModels.get(i).getTypeflux()).add(sentinelReportModels.get(i));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to achieve with standard streams:

The group of child lists can be obtained using a group by:

```
Map<String, List<SentinelReportModel>> map = 
    sentinelReportModels.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(model -> model.getIdentifiantfichier()));
```

This will give you a map of `<identifiantfichier, List<SentinelReportModel>>`.

And this can be process normally as a string/list map.

Your inner loop has a flaw in the sense that it doesn't take into account that previous iterations may have already created a list for the current element's `identifiantfichier` and overwrites it anyway.

Comment: I am in Java 7, then I can't use that but thanks you for the help !